# How can I show enemy health using console?

Tags: source-engine, half-life-2

In PC Gamer's [Prospekt review](http://www.pcgamer.com/prospekt-review/) console is used to compare enemy base health values between Half-Life 2 and a HL 2 mod:

> from [Prospekt's](http://store.steampowered.com/app/399120/) first combat encounter, it felt to me like something
>   was off. The breaking point came during a battle at the start of
>   chapter five, when, in a fit of frustration, I quit out, loaded up
>   Half-Life 2, and used the command console to check out a hunch. Sure
>   enough, the Combine Overwatch Soldier and Elite—the two enemy types
>   you fight throughout the majority of Prospekt—have been given
>   significantly more health.

I would like to do my own tests, for example [MINERVA](http://store.steampowered.com/app/235780/) mod may have increased the enemy health.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have found, it seems like Prospekt used the console command `impulse 103` while looking at the enemies, as this command will tell you the stats of a "monster".

From [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Impulse)

> Prints AI state of the NPC the player is looking at to the console. Requires developer mode.

I'm not entirely sure what is meant by "AI state", as this, to me, implies "hostile" vs. "friendly", but from other sites, it seems that this is what will reveal enemy health to you.

From [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/43362-half-life/cheats):

> While looking at amonster, displays stats.

And [here](https://www.lifewire.com/half-life-cheats-pc-3401956):

> Monster Stats, While Looking at Monster
>
> impulse 103

And [here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Half-Life/Cheats):

> Show monster stats impulse 103

Comment: `/` isn't required, it's the key to open the console and not part of actual command.

Comment: @user598527 it was a quote, so I was leaving it as is, but you're right. I removed the `/`.

Comment: `impulse` requires  `sv_cheats 1` as well, tested with the original Half-Life 2 and Minerva mod.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the developer console is enabled in the game settings (keyboard > advanced). Enable developer mode and cheats with `developer 1` and `sv_cheats 1` commands. 
Aim at an NPC and open console (the game should be automatically paused) and use command `impulse 103`. Example output for [Antlion Soldier](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Antlion_Soldier):

```
State: Combat, npc_antlion: Activity: ACT_RUN  -  Ideal Activity: ACT_RUN
Task 129 (#4), Schedule SCHED_CHASE_ENEMY, 
Enemy is player Moving Leader.
Yaw speed:32.0,Health:  30
Groundent:worldspawn
```

`god` (God mode) and `host_timescale x` (slow down time; the default is `host_timescale 1`, for example `host_timescale 0.25`) can be used as supplementary commands.
Please note that the command tells the **current health** and damage is taken into account, to get **base health** be sure to aim at an intact character.

```
x=<1
```